# Bootnode public address

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

I am trying to deploy an small private Ethereum network using geth. I have a server running geth configured as a miner in my local network. In the other side I have a droplet in DigitalOcean that I want to use as a bootnode to connect future nodes to my network.

I have executed the following commands in my DigitalOcean Droplet:

```
 bootnode --genkey=boot.key 
 bootnode --nodekey=boot.key --addr:$(MY_PUBLICIP):30301
```

And I get the following output from the command instead of my public key that I need to introduce as my enode reference in the future nodes:

```
INFO [10-29|18:13:32.851] New local node record                    seq=1 id=785b198c28c625f8 ip=<nil> udp=0 tcp=0
```

Could please somebody tell how to interpret the output from the bootnode command?

I introduced a netstat command in order to find out whether or not the program is opening a port.

```
ether@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-ams3-01:~$ netstat -l
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                 LISTEN     
udp     6912      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2g:30301 0.0.0.0:*                          
raw6       0      0 [::]:ipv6-icmp          [::]:*                  7          
raw6       0      0 [::]:ipv6-icmp          [::]:*                  7
```

I'm using a standard Ubuntu 18.04 configuration of the basic droplet DigitalOcean, I would like to know if I should configure something else besides the usual compilation of the geth code in order to make a bootnode work.

Thanks any help is welcomed.